# Run specific method in class without sharing

Tags: apex, sharing

Is there a way to run method/code block without sharing, even if the class is with sharing?

Comment: I think you can check sharing before executing the code;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible in the way you describe. You have to put the function that should run without sharing in a separate class that is defined without sharing. Methods defined in that class will be executed without sharing, regardless of the sharing of the calling class.

Comment: That's what i afraided of

Comment: But it's not a bad thing. If implemented correctly, such classes can be a really powerful and secure way to manage logic that needs sharing to be somewhat "loosened" for specific requirements.